# Mysql Locking 3 consecutive interdependent queries

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I don't have a real code sorry. But only a problem explanation.
I would like to understand how is the best way to solve this problem.
I have 3 queries:

- The first one is a long Transaction which performs an SQL INSERT statement in a table.
- The second query COUNTs the number of rows of the previous table after the INSERT took place
- The third query UPDATEs one field of the previously inserted record with the count number retrieved by the second query.

So far so good. My 3 queries are executed correctly.
Now suppose that these 3 queries are executed inside an API call. What happens now is that if multiple API calls are executed too fast and simultaneously, the second COUNT query retrieves a wrong value and consequently the 3th UPDATE has also a wrong value.
Nevertheless I have dead locks on the INSERT query because while making the INSERT, the SELECT COUNT tried to read at the same time on a second api call.

My question is what would be the best approach to solve this kind of problem.
I don't need code. I just would like to understand the best way to go.
Would I need to lock all the tables, for example?

Comment: Can you at least provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?  The datatypes, indexes, etc could give clues.  Also how many rows in step 1?  Can step 2 be performed on the insert list?  Is step 3 updating only one row?  Or all the rows just inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are doing, but this might be faster:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t ...;   -- all columns except count
INSERT IN t ...;   -- the incoming data

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @ct FROM t;

INSERT INTO real_table
    (...)         -- including the count-column last
    SELECT ..., @ct FROM t;  -- Note how count is tacked on last
```